# Android Internal Storage error

Tags: android, storage, internal

I tried to write internal storage somethings.Open an dir.. and fileoutputstream.I managed to write a file but when I try to use this file and get an error(There is not an error at Logcat.When "Startactivity" part run open an dialog.Write "There is a packet parsing error" on the dialog on android device).Actually the file is exist but I don't use the file. My aim with startactivity: open an intent which load the apk file to android device.

My path on internal storage

```
mydir = getDir("mydir", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
filewithmydir = new File(mydir,fileName+".apk");
fileOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream(filewithmydir);
```

Write something to file with progressbar from inputstream(This part is succesfull)

```
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    long total = 0;
    int count;
    while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {

        total += count;
        publishProgress((int) total * 100 / fileLength);

        fileOutPutStream.write(data, 0, count);
    }
```

The part which use the file

```
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(mydir.getAbsolutePath()+"/incomingplus.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);// Error is here!
```

My permissions

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

Comment: what kind of error? exception? can you post the exception?

Comment: There is not an error at Logcat.When "Startactivity" part run open an dialog.Write "There is a packet parsing error" on the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In case you open file by external application, it has not access to your file.
Also you use different variables: `intent` and `intentGuncelle` in
`intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(mydir.getAbsolutePath()+"/incomingplus.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intentGuncelle);// Error is here!`

Comment: I edited intent and intentguncelle variables.Actually in the code both is same.I make mistake when I writing here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the permission in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```